# Wrapping all routes in root route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm trying to wrap all my routes in my root ("/") route so that when I go to localhost:port/ all routes render, been stuck on this problem from quite a while hoping to get help

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Automation from './Component/Automation/automation'
import Login from './Component/Login/login'
import SignUp from './Component/Signup/signup'
import Unprovision from './Component/Unprovision/unprovision'
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import ProtectedRoute from './Component/protectedroute'
import CutOver from './Component/Client/cutover'
// import CheckForExistingSession from './Component/checkForExistingSession'
import Device from './Component/Device/deviceView'
import Product from './Component/Product/productView'
import Wholesale from './Component/Wholesale/wholesaleView'
import permissionManagement from './Component/Permission/permissionListView'
import userManagement from './Component/UserList/userListView'
import userEditView from './Component/UserList/userEditView'
import modelView from './Component/ModelUI/modelView'
import PageNotFound from './Component/pageNotFound/pageNotFound'

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path="/automation" component={Automation} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/unprovision" component={Unprovision} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/cutover" component={CutOver} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/devices" component={Device} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/products" component={Product} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/wholesale" component={Wholesale} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path="/permissionManagement" component={permissionManagement} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path="/userManagement" component={userManagement} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path='/userEditView' component={userEditView} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path='/model' component={modelView} />
            <Route exact path="/pageNotFound" component={PageNotFound} />            
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

This is the version I'm using

```
"react-router": "^3.2.6",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say all routes render on `/`. Is it that all components should render on home page

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes.. !!